# App UI will freeze firebase MLKit for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, ocr, firebase-mlkit

I have following code using to recognize text using Firebase mlkit for ios

```
func runTextRecognition(with image: UIImage) {

            let visionImage = VisionImage(image: image)
            textRecognizer?.process(visionImage){ result, error in
                guard error == nil, let result = result else {

                    self.addImageToView()

                    return
                }

                for block in result.blocks {
                    self.countDown = self.countDown + 1
                    let blockText = block.text

                    let blockFrame = block.frame

                 //do action
                        }
                        else{

                            print("Tag Total Block Count \(result.blocks.count)")
                            print("Tag Milena \(self.countDown)")

                 /*happen only with some images
                   countDown is less than result.blocks.count
                   UI will be freeze*/

                            if (result.blocks.count == self.countDown){
                                self.countDown = 0
                                print("Tag All Milena \(result.blocks.count)")
                                self.addImageToView()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

When text is not recognize inside the block sometime app UI will be freeze in between the loop. I have comment in the code as well. Please anyone can help me to solve this problem.